# SetTimer IDEvent return Value Problems

Tags: winapi, vba, timer

Currently I am trying to implement a timer class in VBA. For that purpose I use the SetTimer and KillTimer functions of the Windows API...

This is the interface from Msdn:

```
  UINT_PTR WINAPI SetTimer(
  __in_opt  HWND hWnd,
  __in      UINT_PTR nIDEvent,
  __in      UINT uElapse,
  __in_opt  TIMERPROC lpTimerFunc
);
```

And this is the way I declared the function wihtin my VBA-Module:

```
Private Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal Handle As Long, _
                                                ByVal TimerIDHandle As Any, _
                                                ByVal ElapseTime As Long, _
                                                ByVal AddressOfAndYourHandlerFunctionName As Long) As Long

                                                'TimerIDHandle is of Type Any so I can pass Nothing to the function
```

I then Call the function this way:

```
Dim TimerID As Long

TimerID = SetTimer(Application.hWndAccessApp, ByVal 0&, Timer.Timeout, AddressOf TimeOutHandler)
```

As Vba does not accept a "Null" I have tried implementing "ByVal 0&". Is this the right way to do it?
Anyway...I call this function several times from the same Application and the function always returns 1 as an Identifier even though, according to Msdn, the function should return a unique ID for each timer that is created in the Window handle of the current Access Application.

Furthermore when I created only one timer the Callback function gets Called, but the Timer ID is given as 0, whereas the Settimer-Function returned a 1 at the time of initialization.
Here is my Callback Function Header:

```
Private Sub TimeOutHandler(ByVal WindowHandle As Long, _
                           ByVal TimerMessage As Long, _ 
                           ByVal TimerID As Long, _ 
                           ByVal ElapsedTime As Long)
```

Where am I wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated of course ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked.  If it failed then it would have returned 0.  You get a 0 for TimerID in the callback because you passed a 0 for the nIDEvent argument when you created the timer.  You'll need to use the value that SetTimer returned to call KillTimer().  Think of it as a timer 'handle'.

You'll never get this code working in 64-bit mode so just declare the 2nd argument as Long.

Comment: Yes, I know it worked, but if I have a running timer (IDEvent returned = 1) on the Current Access Window and want to get a second timer using the Window handle I also used fo the first timer then SetTimer still returns 1, even though it should give me a different IDEvent handle. Or can I Choose whichever IDEvent I want? This might cause trouble as I don't know which Timer IDs Access uses on its Window...By the way: I passed NULL to SetTimer, not 0 ;-)

Comment: If you want *another* timer then you have to pass a different value for nIDEvent.  If you use the same one (0 in your snippet) then you just get the same timer back.

Comment: So it can be any value I want? Won't there be conflicts if Access has Timers running in its Window whose IDs I don't know?

Comment: Yes, that's technically possible if HWND refers to a window that's owned by Access.  I would guess that the Microsoft programmer did that right and used an atom instead of an integer ID to avoid this mishap.  I don't know for a fact.

Comment: Great Help...thanks! I will use the Object Pointers of my Timer-Objects to define hopefully relatively unique IDs...